# Can I display an image in Rails without displaying the database text with it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, web

I'm trying to display a set of images from my database using `image_tag`, but the loop displays the entire database along with the images.

`<%= @tools.each do |tool|%>

<%= link_to( image_tag(tool.image_url, :alt=>"Hello, this is an alt"), "tools/"+tool.id.to_s)%>
<% end %>`

This works to display each of the images and link them to the correct spot, but at the end of the images, there's a bunch of text from the database that shouldn't be there and I couldn't figure out how to remove.

I don't know that it matters, but here's the text:

`[#<Tool id: 3, title: "Screwdriver", description: "a screwdriver", image_url: "1.png", price: #<BigDecimal:4818870,'0.1E1',9(36)>, created_at: "2012-09-16 16:31:10", updated_at: "2012-09-16 16:31:10">, #<Tool id: 5, title: "Hammer", description: "A hammer", image_url: "3.png", price: #<BigDecimal:48167b8,'0.7E1',9(36)>, created_at: "2012-09-20 02:19:35", updated_at: "2012-09-20 02:19:35">]`

Any ideas or tips are much appreciated.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<% @tools.each do |tool|%>
```

No equal sign.

Comment: Wow, that was an easy fix!  But I thought the `=` needed to be there when you're putting Ruby code into an HTML page.  What's the difference between `<%` and `<%=`?

Comment: % executes teh code, %= executes and uses the result basically.

Comment: Exactly as Tony said.  In your case, the result of the each call is the array which was showing up in your HTML page.